# My baby mice is getting out of her wired cage what shall I do?

Tags: cage, mice

I have 2 female (100% female) mice, the one I had first absolutely hates the new one. (Which is weird because they are both definitely females) I went ahead and brought the exact same cage for the new mouse as I did for the original one. The original is fully grown and can not get out of her cage but the new one is smaller and can squeeze her way through the bars. What should I do as my mother just spent $40 on this and I feel bad telling her to buy me a new one. As she grows will she not be able to fit through the bars like my other one?

Answer (score 3):

Get a cheap/used aquarium or glass/plastic habitat with a netted top until she grows large enough that she can't fit through the bars on her intended habitat.

It shouldn't take more than a month or so for her to grow large enough.

Comment: A college friend's mice lived in that sort of setup for years --  large enough aquarium for their wheel and cardboard tubes to play in/gnaw upon along w/ food dish and play/sleeping/digging space. Water bottle was clipped to inside of tank. Mice would sometimes climb up and hang from the screening, apparently with the deliberate intention of teasing the dorm's cat.